# Software adjustment of gamma/brightness settings in Raspbian

Tags: hdmi, video

I am trying to find a way to control the apparent brightness of my external screen on Raspbian Stretch.

In my situation, there is no need to actually control the backlight, as I only want to change the apparent brightness.

On my desktop PC using Ubuntu, I can achieve this using xrandr:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.5
```

As the Raspberry Pi does not appear to be using xrandr by default, I am wondering of there is a way to enable it or if there is an alternative way of controlling the gamma/brightness value without the requirement to control the actual backlight of the screen.

The official [HDMI configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/hdmi-config.md) or [Video options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) documentation does not seem to contain any such setting.

Any information that could be helpful here is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`xrandr` is in the `x11-xserver-utils` package.

```
sudo apt install x11-xserver-utils
```

I haven't been able to test that it works, other than than it runs (and complains "Can't open display" for me; my Pi is headless).

Comment: I belive xrandr is installed by default on Raspbian, it does not seem to be used/supported by the proprietary VideoCore graphics driver though. So unless there is a way to make the driver use xrandr, I wonder how the brightness setting could be influenced any other way.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1274

According to this report, it's currently impossible pending someone changing this in the graphics rendering stack. Compounding this is the devs apparently wanting to move away from GPU dependence, a decision I find questionable, but anyway